# ping command doesn't return when pinging a remote server that is down

Tags: python

I have a function in a python script that basically checks whether a remote server is up or not using ping. If it is not up then it should wait till it is up and only then return. But the script doesn't return if the remote server is down, if the remote server is up then the script returns.

I have tried both subprocess and os.system, I also tried with various parameters in ping command like -c, -w and -W but nothing seems to help. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
def waitTillUp():
    command = "ping -c 1 -W 2 " + remoteServer
    response = os.system(command)

    if response == 0:
        print "UP\n"
    else:
        print "Down\n"
    '''
    args = shlex.split(command)
    p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, err = p.communicate()
    logging.debug("Waiting for the Remote Server to be up")
    while "4 packets transmitted, 4 received" not in output:
        logging.debug("Waiting for the remoteServer to be up")
        p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        output, err = p.communicate()
    '''
```

Ideally it should loop till it is up but just for the sake of checking whether it is returning or not I have just put an if else condition. When the remote server does actually come up, the script is still stuck and not stopping. Once I hit an enter in the window, it returns. Any suggestions are welcome.

Update# 2

Right now I am just trying to do this, not checking for any response or anything. I just hope to let the program fall through to main and then end of program but it is not even doing that.

```
def waitTillUp():
    command = "ping -c 1 " + Params.storageArray    
    response = os.system(command)
```

I am using lot of subprocess.Popen calls one after the other, so is it possible that some buffer is not getting cleared or something of similar sort? Can this be the reason for the weird behavior?

Update# 3

The problem is probably in the reboot call of the remote server before the code that I have pasted. I changed few things and realized that at the function where I am trying to do a reboot, at that point the function is not returning.

This is the complete code. With logging statements I am able to determine that the call for reboot, below marked as the "CULPRIT CALL" is the point where the execution is getting stuck and doesn't proceed till it gets a ENTER key from the user.

```
def waitTillUp():
    command = "ping -c 1 " + remoteServer
    response = os.system(command)

def execCmd(op, command):
    logging.info("Executing %s operation(command: %s)" %(op, command))
    args = shlex.split(command)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, err = p.communicate()
    logging.debug("Output of %s operation: %s" %(op, output))

def install():      
    execCmd("chmod", "ssh root@" + remoteServer + " chmod +x ~/OS*.bin")
    execCmd("reboot", "ssh root@" + remoteServer  + " reboot -nf") ### CULPRIT CALL
    waitTillUp()

def main():
    install()
```

Comment: Did you try looping it this way `while os.system(command) != 0: print "not up"` or something?

Comment: @ForbiddenOverseer Tried that, didn't work, same issue, I have to hit the Enter key for it to return.

Comment: What is the server address that you're trying to ping?

Comment: It is a VM in my company's network. I am able to manually ping to it. It is a 10.X.X.X address. One more interesting thing is that when I try the command "response = os.system(....)" through the python terminal, it returns with a non-zero number (as the server is down) but when I try the same code (without any if condition) it hangs.

Comment: Also, what response are you getting from the command? Check not only for `0` but also for `None` and try it once...?

Comment: Right now I am just doing Update#2, not checking for any response or anything. I just hope to let the program fall through to main and then end of program but it is not even doing that.